# Test Suite for Actions on Google Smart Home Assertion Error

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I'm implementing a Smart Home action, and while running tests on the Test Suite, I got the following error message during an OnOff trait test:

Ok Google. Turn on the WaterMoter
`AssertionError: Expected state to include: {"on":true}, actual state: {"on":false,"online":true}: expected false to be true`

Ok Google. Turn off the WaterMoter

But when we try with the Google Home app everything is working and the response is 200 OK with this data:

```
Apr 30 12:29:54 api.firewires.in node[277153]: Email: firewires.smart.home@gmail.com
Apr 30 12:29:54 api.firewires.in node[277153]: UUID: 6e5c0a41-e9db-4313-b550-f5674d500bf7
Apr 30 12:29:54 api.firewires.in node[277153]: Device: FW_246F28248118#switch_7
Apr 30 12:29:54 api.firewires.in node[277153]: Calling Home Graph
Apr 30 12:29:55 api.firewires.in node[277153]: HomeGraph Called without Error
Apr 30 12:29:55 api.firewires.in node[277153]: HomeGraph Response: {
Apr 30 12:29:55 api.firewires.in node[277153]: "requestId": "6e5c0a41-e9db-4313-b550-f5674d500bf7"
Apr 30 12:29:55 api.firewires.in node[277153]:
```

In Smart Home Report State Dashboard devices showing state:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfORZ.png

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the question, it can be concluded that you’re not using the Report State API correctly. The Test Suite for Google Smart Home derives the state change data from the HomeGraph API and in order to do that a proper implementation of the Report State must be in place.
Please check if the Report State API has been set up and being called correctly. Visit https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state for more information.